# Django DEBUG=False won't upload files to STATIC_ROOT

Tags: python, django, file-upload, imagefield

I'm trying to give the user the ability to upload images on a website I created with `Django` and the images are uploaded fine when running with `DEBIG=True` but the issue is that when `DEBUG=False` the image files doesn't upload to the `MEDIA_ROOT` instead it gets uploaded to `STATIC_DIRS`. Also, even the files that are already in `MEDIA_ROOT` after executing `python manage.py collectstatic` aren't loaded to the template and the image URL gives the `404 Page Not Found` error.

> The CSS and JS files are still served so it means only the media url
> isn't working.

Following are the codes I'm using.

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('Home.urls')),
    path('account/', include('Account.urls')),
]

urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**settings.py**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedStaticFilesStorage'
```

**Note** that I'm using `whitenoise` as the storage backend.

Here is the model code that is used to upload the file.

```
@deconstructible
class PathAndRename(object):
    def __init__(self, sub_path):
        self.path = sub_path

    def __call__(self, instance, filename):
        ext = filename.split('.')[-1]
        filename = '{}.{}'.format(uuid4().hex, ext)
        return os.path.join(self.path, filename)

rename_pp = PathAndRename('img/profile-pictures')

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to=rename_pp, blank=True, null=True, default='img/profile-pictures/default-profile-pic.png')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Profile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        image = Image.open(self.avatar.path)
        if image.width > 100 or image.height > 100:
            output_size = (100, 100)
            image.thumbnail(output_size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
            image.save(self.avatar.path, file_quality=100)
```

Comment: Why would user uploaded files be uploaded to _`STATIC_ROOT`_? User uploaded files are _media_ files and get uploaded to _`MEDIA_ROOT`_ and hence looking at your code, you are getting the correct behaviour. Note: one does not use the static tag to show media files, one simply uses `model_instance.field.url`, hence you would be writing: `{{ profile.avatar.url }}`

Answer (score 0):

When using `DEBUG=True` it means that you are at development side thus your local machine is able to serve the files (media files) but with `DEBUG=False` it is taken like you are now on deployment side.

To serve media files from that, you need to have a bucket(like amazon S3) which will store those files and will get served from there.

So if your media files are working fine when `DEBUG=True`, that means it is fine.

Now all you need is a place to store them.

Comment: Also i don't think we need to run the collectstatic command if using whitenoise as it takes care of that.

Answer (score 0):

I've used this instead of your STATICFILES_STORAGE and when debug=False everything works fine.

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.StaticFilesStorage'
```